# on Selberg trace formula

Tags: modular-forms, laplacian, geodesic, automorphic-forms

The selberg trace formula has two forms: one is for a setting of a semi simple group $G$ and its cocompact subgroup $\Gamma$, and relates the geometric and spectral side of the canonical automorphic representation of $G$, which is normally we are talking about, another is for a Laplacian operator on a Riemannian surface, and relates the spectrum of it with the length of geodesic curves, which seems not a special case of the first form, although of course they have much similarity.  I am just wondering if the second form can be reduced from the first form, what is the relation of them?

Comment: Are you asking if every Riemann surface is of the form $G/\Gamma$?  This is the uniformization theorem.